# Download all images from URL

Tags: images, web, download-manager

I am searching a software to download all images from a given URL with subpages. Means if i have a primary domain named

http://www.thisisatestdomain.com

and this testdomain has the following subpages

http://www.thisisatestdomain.com/about-me
http://www.thisisatestdomain.com/about-me/photos
http://www.thisisatestdomain.com/gallery
http://www.thisisatestdomain.com/contact
http://www.thisisatestdomain.com/contact/1/2/99/43/enter

i want the software to download all images from all URLs listed above. There is a few important criteria for the software:

-Needs so run on Windows and MAC OS
-No online "Software". Only "real" software to download and install on computer
-It can cost money, but cant be a subscription model
-Needs to be simple since many people who are not that tech savvy will work with it

*Does anyone have any ideas?*

Answer (score 1):

The command line program, `wget`, can do most of what you want, but being a command line tool there's a slight learning curve.

Googling for alternatives with a GUI I found [visualwget](https://visualwget.github.io/) but I can't personally vouch for it (or its safety of the executable on Github) as I've never used it personally.

Comment: This don't fits the bill. wget just downloads a single url, but the question is asking about getting all the images and also following links (ie, parsing html). Far beyond what wget can do, as far as I know.

Comment: No, it can- from the wget man page:  "Wget can follow links in HTML, XHTML, and CSS pages, to create local versions of remote web sites, fully recreating the directory structure of the original site.  This is sometimes referred to as 'recursive downloading.'"

Comment: Interesting, didn't knew that it can do that.